# Griffon 1.5 project , unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, griffon

I have an old(ish) griffon project (1.5) I have to maintain. I'm trying to install and run it on a new PC via griffon run_app but I'm getting a 'Some dependencies could not be resolved ' for some plugins  ..

```
-=MISSING =-
? installer-0.8 not found in any repository
? lombok-0.5.0 not found in any repository
? miglayout-1.0.0 not found in any repository
? spock-0.7 not found in any repository
? rest-1.1.1 not found in any repository
+ swing-1.4.0 from griffon-local
? glazedlists-2.0.0 not found in any repository
```

(these were hand keyed so any spelling mistakes are mine) ..

This is from a working application so the config was originally correct

Is it possible these have moved and where can I find them ?

Comment: It could be useful to have the GAV (groupId, artifactId, version)  for each missing dependency. Could you share the pom you're using?

Comment: I don't think this version of Griffon used a POM  .. just a BuildConfig.groovy file  ..

Comment: repositories {
            griffonHome()

           // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency     resolution
           // from public Maven repositories
           //mavenLocal()
           mavenCentral()
           mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
           mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
           mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
           mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
          //jcenter()
          //bintray(username: 'foo', repository: 'bar')
          //bintray('foo/bar')
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the decommission of the Griffon Artifact Portal. See http://griffon-user.74797.x6.nabble.com/Griffon-Plugin-Portal-shutting-down-on-Dec-31st-td75.html for more information.

You can still download old plugins from http://griffon-framework.org/portal-storage/

This is **not** a link to an artifact portal but you can use the links to download the binaries, for example

```
griffon install-plugin http://griffon-framework.org/portal-storage/packages/plugin/glazedlists/2.0.0/griffon-glazedlists-2.0.0.zip
```

I'd also recommend you to comment out the plugins found in `application.properties`  and manually install each one after the other, starting with swing, followed by miglayout, then glazedlists.

Finally, it would be good it the application were to be migrated to the latest Griffon release (2.7.0) http://griffon-framework.org/guide/2.7.0/#_appendix_migration

Comment: Thanks  .. I thought it had gone ... I'll see about getting it upgraded to 2.7  ..